# Restricting Type Combinations in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two types:

```
type TypeLetter = "TypeA" | "TypeB"

type TypeNumber = "Type1" | "Type2"
```

I want to limit the ways I can combine values from these types so that only `TypeA` and `Type1` can be together and only `TypeB` and `Type2` can be together.

How can I create a type `Restricted` to make such a thing happen? In other words, where these are valid:

```
const valid1: Restricted = {
   valLetter: "TypeA" 
   valNumber: "Type1"
}

const valid2: Restricted = {
   valLetter: "TypeB" 
   valNumber: "Type2"
}
```

But this is not:

```
const nope: Restricted = {
   valLetter: "TypeB" 
   valNumber: "Type1"
}
```

Comment: Does this need to work only with these two combinations or are you looking for something that would get all combinations of a union of `n` types, like if you added a `TypeC` and `Type3` in there for instance

Comment: Great question. Let's just say these two for now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following would work for just those two. You can use `const` types.

```
type Restricted = {
    valLetter: 'TypeA',
    valNumber: 'Type1'
} | {
    valLetter: 'TypeB',
    valNumber: 'Type2'
};

const nope: Restricted = {
    valLetter: "TypeB",
    valNumber: "Type1"
} // Type '"Type1"' is not assignable to type '"Type2"'.
```

Comment: This is helpful, but what if one of the types isn't a literal or a `string` and is instead another user-defined type? I am happy to edit my question if it will make that clearer

Comment: Swapping out the literal for another type shouldn't change anything. As long as you have the different combinations of object types together in a union, then typescript can figure it out